# Does the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \cdot \frac{e_n}{n}$ converge in $\ell^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis

> Determine whether the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \cdot \frac{e_n}{n}$ converges in $\ell^1$, where $e_n = (0,0,0, \dots, 1, \dots, ,0 ,0, \dots)$ where $1$ is at the nth place.

To conclude that this series converges I need to figure out if the vector sequence $(s_n)_{n =1}^\infty$ of the partial sums converges that is $\| s_n - y \| \to 0$ for some $y \in \ell^1$.

How do I figure out what this sequence of partial sums must be? I think that the definition is little confusing here.

Comment: If it converged then it would converge entrywise and the limit would be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \cdot \frac{e_n}{n}$. But the limit does not belong to $\ell^1.$

Answer (score 1):

$$(s_n)_i = \begin{cases}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}i; & i\leq n \\ 0; &i > n\end{cases}$$

So let $m>n$ then

$$\Delta_{m;n} =\left\|s_m-s_n\right\|_{\ell^1}=\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^m \frac 1i$$

We then note that for any $M>0$ and any $n>0$ we can find $m>n$ such that $\Delta_{m;n}>M$. Thus this sequence does not converge.